# C# - Use of unassigned local variable that has already been defined

Tags: c#, variables, compiler-errors, declaration

I have declared the boolean variable "activated" outside of my for loop, I am changing its value inside the for loop, and when I am trying to use it outside of my loop **next to the return statement**, it says that it is unassigned. Any ideas?

```
private bool validityCheck()
    {
        char[] invalidCharacters = { '*', '\'', '.', ';', ':', ',' };

        bool activated;

        for (int i = 0; i < invalidCharacters.Length; i++)
        {
            activated = false;
            if (textBox1.Text.Contains(invalidCharacters[i]))
            {
                ErrorHandling(45, "Fields contain invalid characters", false);
                textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                activated = true;
            }

            if (textBox2.Text.Contains(invalidCharacters[i]))
            {
                if (activated)
                    ErrorHandling(45, "Fields contain invalid characters", false);
                textBox2.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }

        return activated;
    }
```

I definitely expect that to happen if I simply remove `for`:

```
private bool validityCheck()
{
    bool activated;
    return activated;
}
```

But since the loop will always have at least one iteration I expect compiler to be smart enough to figure that out and understand that `actived` is assigned before code leaves the loop. (I've heard of term "definite assignment" possibly related to this, but C# spec is too hard for me to parse yet)

Comment: I've added some explanation why you are asking the question - please review and improve if I missed something. Also don't tag questions about C# with "visual-studio" as that tag is for interacting/coding *for* VS and "use VS as text editor/IDE".

Comment: What about assigned a 'false' value when declared instead of in for loop. E.g. bool assigned = false;

Comment: The answer from @phillipngan is correct. The compiler does not do a complex analysis to look for this kind of dependency. In your code, there's no way for the `invalidCharacters` array to be zero-length, but the analysis is not that smart. If it was zero-length, then `activated` is never initialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft documentation for error [CS0165](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165) `Use of unassigned local variable 'activated'` states

> This error is generated when the compiler encounters a construct that
> might result in the use of an unassigned variable, even if your
> particular code does not. This avoids the necessity of overly complex
> rules for definite assignment.

The error exists to relieve the compiler of the task of determining that a value has been assigned when it is in a loop (something happens when it is inside the body of an `if` statement.)

The easiest way of avoiding the error is to assign a value to the variable before the loop.